# Entity Framework Handle broken connection by reopening?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, database-connection

We have an application using EF 4.1 that has a unreliable connection to the DB.

We keep having the error:
"Execution of the command requires an open and available connection. The connection's current state is broken."

Preferably, the solution would occur at the EF level, re-opening the connection whenever broken.

I tried using the StateChange event on the connection, but it does not appear to fire on change to broken.

Comment: How long do you keep a Connection (Context) alive?

Comment: The context could be open for however long the user is editing the record.
It's when connectivity is lost and the connect is Broken.

Comment: EF may be able to reconnect but then your cached records become 'foreign'. You'll have to set this up like a Web app, ie use detached data. Reconnect when the Save button is hit.